# How play audio from a video file from specific frame in python

Tags: python, audio, video, kivy, ffpyplayer

I would like to know how I could go about playing audio from **a specific position** in a video file, using **ffpyplayer**.

I know how to set the frame I want to start playing at in opencv but not in ffplayer.

Any ideas or suggestions would help a ton. Here is what I have came up with.

```py
import cv2
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer

video_path=videoName

def PlayVideo(video_path):
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 7200)

    player = MediaPlayer(video_path)

    while True:
        grabbed, frame = video.read()
        audio_frame, val = player.get_frame()

        if not grabbed:
            print("End of video")
            break
        
        if cv2.waitKey(28) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    
        cv2.imshow("Video", frame)
        if val != 'eof' and audio_frame is not None:
            #audio
            img, t = audio_frame

    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

PlayVideo(video_path)
```

Comment: don't use OpenCV. it's for computer vision, not for decoding video. use PyAV. and use a proper GUI toolkit for the presentation. OpenCV is not a GUI toolkit, it's for computer vision. try tkinter, it comes with python. or Qt perhaps.

Comment: I will be using the computer vision side of OpenCV later in the project. Is there a different audio library I can use?

Comment: do you know that "setting the position" is called "seeking"? ffpyplayer does that. just browse the documentation. -- ffpyplayer uses SDL already, so maybe use that, or pygame, or proper Qt, for your video display needs. or **kivy**, which seems to have spawned ffpyplayer. -- your code's indentation (which is syntax in python!) was horribly broken.